# PFUser Current User check not working in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfuser

I have an `if ([PFUser currentUser])` check in my AppDelegate.  I created a user then deleted them, but `if ([PFUser currentUser])` returns true and has the user's former objectId even though they have been deleted from the Data Browser.

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary     *)launchOptions
{

[Parse setApplicationId:PARSE_APPLICATION_ID clientKey:PARSE_CLIENT_KEY];

UIViewController *startingVC;

[[PFUser currentUser] refresh];

if ([PFUser currentUser]) 
    NSLog(@"current user: %@", [[PFUser currentUser] objectId]);
```

And current user returns the objectId of a deleted user

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `[[PFUser currentUser] refresh]` before your if statements.

Comment: Didn't work.  I still get the objectId of a deleted user.  Feel like that should work though...

Comment: @user1840001 Does this only happen in the AppDelegate?

Comment: Perhaps use `refresh:` that lets you get error output so you can see if you got a "not found" error when trying the refresh?

Comment: No, the objectId of the deleted user shows up in other classes as well.

Comment: Deleting the user won't remove the pointer from other classes, but trying to resolve that pointer will return a null object